# iptables-restore not working after iptables-save

Tags: iptables

I am trying the below

with `iptables-save > test.rules` i am saving the saved rules file

then with command `iptables-restore test.rules`, i am trying to restore the rules

On `iptables-restore`, seeing below error.

```
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): quota2: option "--name" cannot be inverted.

Error occurred at line: 106
```

Below is Line 106 generated with iptables-save

```
-A bw_global_alert -m quota2 ! --name globalAlert  --quota 2097152
```

What could be the reason, i expect this basic save and restore to work without issues.

Note : All commands are run as root on custom board.

Comment: *"option --name cannot be inverted"* - delete the exclamation mark